Frozen can safety
I have cans (most likely glass cans) stocked in a barn. During winter temperatures may sometimes become negative, leading freezing/thawing.
Since the cans are not altered, it is safe for me to consume the contents ?
I assume that this is not a problem given that, for example during transport, canned goods can undergo the same constraints.
Thanks

In my universe, "glass cans" are not a thing - those two terms go together about as well as "woolen anvils" or "steel pillows". Yes, the activity of preserving food in glass jars is called "canning", but English Is Weird.

OK I can suppose you're right (English is not my language) but it seems many people understood and 2 of them answered something useful. The main target in my question was about freezing cycles not canning methods, also because there are glass jars and metal jars (or cans ?). A usefull comment - for me and others - could be to specify: "in english you should use this term for "glass cans", this term for "metal cans" this term for whatever, at least we could improve our english.

It is possible that expansion of the contents caused by freezing could compromise canning jars' seals. I would expect most jars to break before this happened but a wide-mouth jar with a minimal shoulder might be streamlined enough to allow it if there were very little headspace.
As with all home-canned food, you should check the vacuum seal before opening and consuming. Do not consume cans which are not still under vacuum. Beyond that (and beyond the obvious risk of broken glass), freeze/thaw cycles do not present a safety risk.

If by "glass cans" you mean canning jars, there are ones that are designed to freeze without incident (wider from bottom to top, with no shoulder at the top) and those will, as designed, freeze without incident (though depending what the canned food is, it may have a loss of texture due to being frozen and be less appealing.)
Other shapes will commonly break if frozen, and transporting them (or metal cans, which will bulge and/or burst) in the winter has a degree of managing how long they spend (in boxes, in trucks) between heated warehouses, and what percentage of loss is acceptable in transport. If storing in an unheated building, a below-ground level area (cellar) is typically best to moderate temperatures and prevent freezing.
Some canned items have enough sugar or salt that they will not freeze at 0°C and those may tolerate a bit of freezing weather without freezing due to that.
